# String Compression

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, interview-questions, compression

> Implement a method to perform basic string compression using the counts
> of repeated characters.
>
> For example, the string "aabcccccaaa" would become "a2b1c5a3". If the
> "compressed" string would not become smaller than the original string, your method should return
> the original string. You can assume the string has only uppercase and lowercase letters (a - z).

My solution is:

[GitHub](https://github.com/baishakh/cracking-the-coding-interview-6th-edition/blob/3ac5470f6d582c33379af3f2e0adc546981abd8b/src/main/java/com/firefly/ctci/ch01/string_compression/StringCompressionNaive.java)

```
public class StringCompression {

  public static String compress(String input) {
    if (input == null) {
      return null;
    }

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    char prevChar = input.charAt(0);
    int lengthSoFar = 1;

    for (int index = 1; index < input.length(); index++) {
      char currentChar = input.charAt(index);

      if (prevChar == currentChar) {
        lengthSoFar++;
      } else {
        output.append(prevChar);
        output.append(lengthSoFar);

        // reset counters
        prevChar = currentChar;
        lengthSoFar = 1;
      }
    }
    output.append(prevChar);
    output.append(lengthSoFar);

    return output.toString().length() <= input.length() ? output.toString() : input;
  }
}
```

Comment: i would suggest only one change, the character abbccc translates into a1b2c3 ...rather than doing this, just keep single characters directly. E.g: above string should translate to ab2c3 . Also, you are calling output.toString() twice, you can get by doing it only once.

Answer (score 3):

For input "fooo", the implementation returns "f1o3",
which is the same length, and violates one of the requirements:

> If the "compressed" string would not become smaller than the original string, your method should return the original string.

The fix is in the `return` statement: change `<=` to `<`.

---

Another corner case is when the input is empty, the statement `char prevChar = input.charAt(0);` will throw `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

---

Lastly, a performance pitfall in the return statement,
`output.toString()` creates a new string,
therefore the following may result in double computation:

> ```
> return output.toString().length() < input.length() ? output.toString() : input;
> ```

You could instead benefit from the `length()` method of `StringBuilder`:

```
return output.length() < input.length() ? output.toString() : input;
```

Answer (score 1):

Generates an out of bounds exception if passed an empty (but not `null`) string.

The `new StringBuilder()` should be passed an initial size for the character buffer, to avoid continuous reallocations.  Lacking any other reasonable value, I’d recommend passing in the original string length.

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input.length());
```